# spark sql window function lag

Tags: scala, apache-spark, window-functions

I am looking at the `window` slide function for a Spark `DataFrame` in Scala.

I have a `DataFrame` with columns `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`, `date`, `volume` and `new_col`.

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    date     volume new_col
                        201601  100.5   
                        201602  120.6   100.5
                        201603  450.2   120.6
                        201604  200.7   450.2
                        201605  121.4   200.7`
```

Now I want to add a new column with name(`new_col`) with one row slided down, as shown above.

I tried below option to use the window function.

```
val windSldBrdrxNrx_df = df.withColumn("Prev_brand_rx", lag("Prev_brand_rx",1))
```

Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: @Ramesh till Spark 2.0, users had to use `HiveContext` instead of `SQLContext` to apply window functions. `HiveContext` is created in the same way as `SQLContext` by passing an instance of `SparkContext`. If I remember correctly, you also need you include `org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.10` with an appropriate version for your Spark distribution.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You are doing correctly all you missed is `over(window expression)` on `lag`

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((201601, 100.5),
  (201602, 120.6),
  (201603, 450.2),
  (201604, 200.7),
  (201605, 121.4))).toDF("date", "volume")

val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy("date")  

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lag

val leadDf = df.withColumn("new_col", lag("volume", 1, 0).over(w))

leadDf.show()

+------+------+-------+
|  date|volume|new_col|
+------+------+-------+
|201601| 100.5|    0.0|
|201602| 120.6|  100.5|
|201603| 450.2|  120.6|
|201604| 200.7|  450.2|
|201605| 121.4|  200.7|
+------+------+-------+
```

This code was run on Spark shell 2.0.2

Comment: I don't have 1.5.2 setup and facing issue with maven to load 1.5.2 (spark-hive jar) in my machine.

Comment: I am able to create the hive context now. But still i get the same error.

Comment: i think since the dataframe is created using the sqlcontext i still cannot use the window function.

Answer (score 3):

You can import below two packages, which will resolve the issue of lag dependencies.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lead, lag}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
```