# Adding new column of previous date for account in table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose you have a table with snapshots of accounts from the past 4 years, 1 row per date/account pair. (Note accounts don't need to have a row for every day).

For simplicity suppose there are 3 columns: `acct_number`, `date` and `balance`. How would you add 2 more columns to each row that are the date/balance for that account for the previous date recorded in the table?

It seems like sorting by `acct_number` and date then "offsetting by one" and joining to the original table is a promising approach but I don't know how you'd implement this.

Comment: Perhaps `Window` aggregation and `lag()` is what you need. https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spark sql window function lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158115/spark-sql-window-function-lag)

Comment: Yes, this was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use Windows functionality with a lag of 1.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = load_my_df()

val frame = Window.partitionBy("acct_number").orderBy("date")
val df_new = df.withColumn("prev_balance", lag("balance", 1, null).over(frame))
```

Great examples here: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-window-functions/

Documentation: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html